# How to append a div into labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pega

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/praveendubbaka/qoemfwgr/27/)

how to append a div in to labels. within each radio group and its wrapper div.

I have a radio buttons group code generated dynamically, so I can't add static helper text to labels using HTML.

I am placing div under radio group div and adding div with helper text and wrapping each radio group with another div, then using append. I am adding its only helper text div to its labels using classes.

before  screen [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rYTU.png)

After screen  [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tXDp.png)

```
<div class="helperTextWrapper" >

<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes</label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText2">No</label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div>
<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2">no helper text</div>

</div>

<div class="helperTextWrapper" >

<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes</label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText2">No</label>
   </span>
</div>
    <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText3">Not sure</label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div>
<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2">no helper text</div>
<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3">not sure helper text</div>

</div>
```

I want to Append Yes helper text into  Yes  using jQuery like this but my script is adding multiple/duplicate divs:

`````
   $("div.helperTextWrapper ").each(function(index) {

  $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText1');
   $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText2');
    $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText3');

    });


<div class="helperTextWrapper" >

<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes
           <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText2">No
        <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2">no helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>

</div>




<div class="helperTextWrapper" >

<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes
           <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText2">No
        <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2">no helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
    <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText3">Not sure
        <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3">not sure helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>

</div>

````
`````

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/praveendubbaka/qoemfwgr/27/

Comment: Are you trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/hu3fzknr/18/ ?

Comment: I want to append <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div> into <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes</label>

Comment: its should look like this <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div> </label>

Comment: $(".RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1 ").each(function() {
  
  $(this).appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText1');
  
    });
    
        $(".RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2 ").each(function() {
  
  $(this).appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText2');
  
    });
    
            $(".RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3 ").each(function() {
  
  $(this).appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText3');
  
    });

Comment: I believe that https://jsfiddle.net/98gwq7vr/8/ covers what you want. Takes an extra `find()` inside the `appendTo()` to keep the same container reference.

Comment: @PaulT. Perfect , thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.helperTextWrapper').each(function(){

$(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1').appendTo($(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperText1'));
$(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2').appendTo($(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperText2'));
$(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3').appendTo($(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperText3'));

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/praveendubbaka/t71oae3b/46/